# How to hide a list entry in a Wordpress sidebar widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to hide a list entry within a sidebar widget in WordPress. Here's a screenshot. The sidebar widget labeled with "A." consists of 4 combo boxes. There's an item called "Neues Inserat hinzufügen" in the first combo box labelled "Werkstatt". My goal is to hide this item.

[image]

I already tried lots of different approaches and the following one using jQuery seems the best one. But it doesn't work, either the complete combo box disappears or the entry "Neues Inserat hinzufügen" does not disappear at all. Here's my code snippet from the `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function js_hide_list_entry() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div span:contains('Neues Inserat hinzufügen')").parent("div").hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'js_hide_list_entry' );
?>
```

Any idea where the bug is?

**Update according to `Andrei Gheorghiu` answer:**

I tried your code snippet within the functions.php in my WordPress installation. But I got the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. I searched for this issue and found out, that in the noConflict() mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available. So I slightly modified your code to this:

```
<?php
function js_hide_list_entry() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div").filter(function() { 
          return ($(this).text().indexOf('Neues Inserat hinzufügen') > -1) 
        }).closest('div').hide();
      });
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'js_hide_list_entry' );
?>
```

No more errors now, but the list entry is still present :(

I guess the action hook `wp_footer` works, otherwise I won't get any errors thrown inside the script, correct?

Comment: why not just $('#select2-result-label-5').parent().hide()

Comment: The last number (in this case "5") is dynamically assigned. Everytime the page is built, this number can range from 1 to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly targeting `<span>`s containing your text inside `<div>`s, but the text is in a text-node inside the `<div>` itself, so it's sibling to the `<span>`. This will (most likely) work:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
  $(window).on('load', filterResults);
  $('select').on('select2:opening', filterResults);
  function filterResults(){
    $("li>.select2-result-label").filter(function() { 
      return ($(this).text().indexOf('Neues Inserat hinzufügen') > -1) 
    }).closest('li').hide();
  }
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Test:

```js
(function($){
  $(window).on('load', filterResults);
  $('select').on('select2:opening', filterResults);
  function filterResults(){
    $("div").filter(function() { 
      return ($(this).text().indexOf('Neues Inserat hinzufügen') > -1) 
    }).closest('div').hide();
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>bla bla bla Neues Inserat hinzufügen</span></div>
<div><span>bla bla bla</span></div>
<div><span>Neues Inserat hinzufügen bla bla bla </span></div>
<div><span>bla bla bla</span></div>
<div><span>bla bla bla </span>
  Neues Inserat hinzufügen
</div>
<div><span>bla bla bla </span>
  <p><strong>Neues Inserat hinzufügen</strong></p>
</div>
```

If it doesn't check if:

- you are calling `<?php get_footer(); ?>` in your template
- you are adding the content you want to hide after `$(document).ready` has fired, via `$.ajax()` - in this case, you need to run your function after each `$.ajax()` call.

Note I also replaced your `:contains()` selector with a `.filter()`, which is way faster.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, but I am still out of luck. Please compare to the "Update" note in my initial question.

Comment: Before I update my answer, could you specify how you are loading the search results? Is it an ajax call?

Comment: I modified my answer. I named the filtering function, so it can be ran multiple times. I run it once on page load and once on opening the select2.

Comment: I am not sure how the loading of the search results work. How can I find out? I am a bloody newbie to WordPress :-/ Here's the website http://autoregional.ch - does this help?

Comment: When I add your new code to the `functions.php` file, the entire body disappears. Only the header and footer remain.

Comment: That's good news. It means the results are already in the page. Try it now. This should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your update. But I am unfortunately still without luck. I now have adopted your code to the functions.php, but nothing changed (cp. the code snippet I added in my initial question). Any further ideas what I could do?

Comment: Is there any chance I can inspect it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142111/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-salocinx).